# Chrome extension development: Recommendable keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am currently thinking of recommendable keyboard shortcut combinations to be used in order to not conflict with default keyboard shortcuts for Chrome or any other application potentially conflicting on Linux, Windows or Mac OS X.

Which one would you consider the one having the best compatibility and lowest likelihood of conflicting with other shortcuts on all systems?

1. Alt+key
2. Alt+Ctrl+key
3. Alt+Shift+key
4. Alt+Ctrl+Shift+key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [Chrome's keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/topic/25799?hl=en&ref_topic=14678), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>foo</kbd> is probably the least-used singular modifying key combo, as long as <kbd>foo</kbd> != <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, or <kbd>Home</kbd>.

There are no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>foo</kbd> shortcuts used by Chrome.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>foo</kbd> would probably feel quite comfortable for most Chrome users, as long as <kbd>foo</kbd> != <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>,<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>,  <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or <kbd>Del</kbd>.

You could also encourage your user to choose their own shortcuts within **chrome://extensions > Keyboard shortcuts**.

Comment: Thanks Chris. So I will most probably stick to Alt + foo combinations.